# split(' ') function not giving correct results Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array which takes user input

```
var str = document.getElementById('input1');

var arr = str.split(' ');
```

In some cases the array elements contain spaces.  Cannot pin point the exact case, happens intermittently. But mostly when

```
str = 'Some \' value \' \' in input'
```

Is there a more reliable way to split the input string into individual words divided by space?

Comment: Any chance you provide the exact input that does confuse you?

Comment: We cannot help you if you cannot give us an accurate description of the problem. Your sample input most *definitely* does not produce your described behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand the question, but if you want to break the word at spaces, then you probably want to make one break at any number of spaces next to each other.

```
"some string    that has spaces".split(/\s+/g)
```